# When is it not possible to exploit spatial locality in cache?

Tags: caching, memory-management, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

We are given a processor whose instructions operate on 8 - byte operands and whose instructions are also encoded using 8 bytes. We are using a 16 kilo-byte,
4-way set associative cache that contains 1024 sets. The cache has 4 * 1024 = 4096 cache lines in total. That means, each cache line is 16KB=4096 = 4 bytes, so each operand and each instruction needs to be stored in two cache lines, which will require 2 accesses to the cache for each load/store operation and instruction fetches. We are told that the cache cannot apply spatial locality, but why? What does spatial locality mean in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your machine doesn't have single byte loads/stores at all?

If every load is a full cache line (or multiple whole cache lines), then bringing a line into cache for one load will never benefit another load that's spatially nearby.

(Unless you have hardware prefetching to detect sequential accesses and start fetching adjacent cache lines...)

Comment: No, the machine doesn't have single byte loads stores. Isn't the definition of spatial locality that "nearby data will be accessed in the near future"?

Comment: @jannè: yes.  exactly.  If your cache lines are so small that loading a value doesn't bring in any nearby values you didn't actually load, then spatial locality in your code doesn't help you.